How does this LDR circuit work?
All I know is that when I turn the lights off, the LED should light up, but I don't know how and why it works. Can you help me? I'd like to know how it works.

The 10k there is a potentiometer.
The transistor is BC547
I need to know how the circuit works and the components functions

Was it a task for you to figure out how it works? What help do you need to figure out how it works? Do you understand what LDRs, resistors, or transistors do in a circuit?

Oh my apologies, i forgot to specify this at the title, so i'd like to know how it works, like why the led lights up when i turn off the lights, also every component functions in the circuit

A good answer is going to depend on how much you already know - I could give an answer to an expert in 2 lines or less. Or 6 pages worth of explanation to someone who doesn't know Jack. And that still might not be enough.

Welp, i'd say my knowledge is very basic in electronics

During light the voltage across LDR is below 0.7V so transistor is not conducting and Led doesn’t glow.
Once dark the voltage across LDR goes higher so base become supplied, the transistor is conducting and Led glows.

Hm i see, thank you!

Sorry to interrupt you, but can you explain how the pottentiometer acts in the circuit?

@fireBreaker_2007 it's not a potentiometer in that circuit ... it is a variable resistor ... the 10 k resistor and the LDR form a potentiometer of sorts

The variable resistor sets at what light intesitity the Led changes state from on to off and vice versa.
